# connecting to azure sql database (or azure datawarehouse, azure SSAS) from power bi service

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to find a suitable source of information that takes me through connecting power BI service to azure sql database (and or /azure sql data warehouse and  or /azure SSAS or SSAS).

I tried to connect to the above mentioned sources from power bi service with steps:  Get Data > Create Content > Databases > Get; where I got 3 options such as 'Azure SQL Database', 'Azure SQL Data Warehouse', 'SSAS', and 'Spark on Azure HDInsight'.

When I tried to connect to 'Azure SQL Database',  OR 'Azure SQL Data Warehouse', the service is prompting me as follow:

**This data source is available in Power BI Desktop, which just takes a minute to install. After you connect to the data source in Desktop, you can publish a report with that data source to the Power BI service**.  Why am I getting this message instead of 'connect' option?

I am using Power BI free license. Do I need Power BI Pro OR Premium subscription to be able to connect directly to Azure services?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to items directly from the service is limited. As the messages show you need to install Power BI Desktop locally on your machine, use that to connect to the Azure SQL DB, Azure DWH etc, then load it to the service.

[image]

You can create a basic file with just the connection, then build the report in the service, but using PBI Desktop top allows more creation of DAX measures and the service is limited to the function you can use to build reports. You should view PBI Service as a place to consume the report, not build, or do small alterations only.

As they are Azure services, and have set the fire wall rules to allow connections  from other Azure services, the connection you set in PBI Desktop will connect without issue.

Power BI Free doesn't limit your connections, just the way that you share reports and other content. You can connect to Azure service and other without Pro/Premium

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, John; however, with some examples over internet, I found screenshot which shows link to connect to Azure SQL Database (Azure SQL data warehouse) from power bi source (without a recommendation to use power bi desktop). I appreciate your efforts concern; unfortunately there isn't direct point-to-point explanation about the connections;

Comment: if you could refer to the info on this link, you would understand what I am trying to get  : https://radacad.com/power-bi-get-data-from-azure-sql-database

Comment: That method has been deprecated and removed, as it was direct query only and you could not do transformations, and DAX formulas in the service. Desktop is now the primary method of connecting, or you use Dataflows in the service, then connect desktop to those

Answer (score 0):

Connect to Azure SQL Database: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5953/create-power-bi-connection-to-azure-sql-database/

Connect to Azure Analysis Services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-connect-pbi